# Adding Top Link via a custom module - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

I have some custom module, on activating this module I want to show a "**Custom Module Link**" as a **top link**. Please refer the snapshot below.

How can I achieve this? This link should redirect to one of the Customer account navigation link.

[image: toplink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Custom</label><url>YOUR_URL_KEY</url><title>Custom</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
     </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Where I have to add this?

Comment: in your module's layout file or local.xml @sree

Comment: I added the code in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule/myModule.xml in the top just below <layout>. the code is not working.. I cleared the cache too..

Comment: provide your code.. what you have added in `<url>` tag?? @sree

Comment: `<default><reference name="top.links"><action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Custom</label><url>MyModule/customBlock/customFile/</url><title>Custom</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action></reference></default>
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation"><action method="addLink" translate="label" module="MyModule">
            <name>MyModule_customBlock_customFile</name>
            <path>MyModule/customBlock/customFile/</path>
            <label>Custom</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
`

Comment: Since I want to link to the "Custom" in the customer_account_navigation I provided the same path to the URL in your code

Comment: In url tag put proper path with routname_controller_action @sree

Comment: other than cache removal any other procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Top-links are generaly managed in Magento through `layout.xml` files. To add a link to top links, you need to add an xml code to layout files.

Please refere to this http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-add-top-links-in-magento/

**EDIT:**

Please put this code under `<reference name="top.links">` and before closing tag `</reference>` in your `local.xml`

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Your label module</label>
    <url>your custom url</url>
    <title>Your title module</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <position>2</position>
</action>
```

Comment: I added like this.. But Not working
`<default><reference name="top.links"><action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Custom</label><url>MyModule/customBlock/custom‌​File/</url><title>Cu‌​stom</title><prepare>true<prepare‌​/><urlParams/><posit‌​ion>2</position></a‌​ction></reference></‌​default> <customer_account> <reference name="customer_account_navigation"><action method="addLink" translate="label" module="MyModule"> <name>MyModule_customBlock_customFile</name> <path>MyModule/customBlock/customFile/</path> <label>Custom</label> </action> </reference> </customer_account>`